# Disable image magnification in browser

Tags: html, css, iframe, magnification, magnify

If I view an image that's larger than my browser, the image automatically gets resized to fit the browser and a magnifying glass glass appears (with a little plus sign in it) and enlarges the image if I click it.  Can this feature be disabled?  I'm particularly interested in doing this in an iframe... for example, if I had `<iframe width=500 height=500 scr='myimage.jpg'>`
And the jpg is 1000px x 1000px, my mouse pointer will become a magnifying glass and enlarges it if clicked.  Can I disable this with css or another method?

Comment: Why are you using an iFrame? Just use `<img>` and manually set a height and width using CSS.

Comment: This has to do with another post of mine about getting an image from an FTP site and putting it in an IMG tag.  It won't work with firefox for some reason, but I can put it in an iframe.  See post here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900916/html-using-an-ftp-file-in-an-img-tag-not-working-on-firefox

Comment: This can probably only be done with a browser-specific extension.

Comment: Uh. Isn't this really unsafe to do because you're giving out your FTP server's username and password?

Comment: Yes, I mention that in my other post.  It's not an issue in my situation, but normally you shouldn't do that.